# Is a telegram different from a datagram?

Tags: protocol-theory

I am reading about field buses and for instance the HART protocol and PROFIBUS call their level 2 frames telegrams. Is this on purpose to differentiate from datagrams (a term used for instance in the IP protocol) in a qualitative way?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practically, it's the same thing.
But as far as I know, the word "datagram" is not used in some industrials protocols because they don't always carry data, sometimes they are used for control.

So it's just a semantic difference for me.